# Error in Ubuntu SDK while writing an app for 14.10

Tags: ubuntu-sdk

On my PC I run Ubuntu 14.04 and I try to write an app for my Nexus 4 with Ubuntu 14.10. So i created a kit for 14.10 with i386-architecture. When I create a new Project there is a red line under the command "import Ubuntu.Components 1.1" with the hint "Unable to parse file var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/plugins.qmltypes

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I usually see that error as well. However it is just a warning and if you have the kits configured as explained at [developer.ubuntu.com](http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/sdk/tutorials/click-targets-and-device-kits/) then your app should run on the Nexus 4 without any issue.